# List all conversations in Pidgin for one day

Tags: bash, logging, pidgin, notification-area

I got a lot of messages yesterday while I was working on something else so I couldn't read them.
Then unfortunately my Ubuntu-machine restarted before I could see who was writing there.

I guess The only solution to find out who was contacting me, would be to view

- all Pidgin-logs at once
- or a history of all notification-messages in ubuntu

A perfect solution would be, if the logs could be [viewed with added colors like I requested here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3017/how-can-i-view-an-irc-log-file-with-added-colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view all chat-logs of `2014-06-09` with

```
ls ~/.purple/logs/*/*/*/2014-06-09*
```

or all logs of all jabber protocols with

```
ls ~/.purple/logs/jabber/*/*/2014-06-09*
```

To look inside all logs on the console, you can create a file `/usr/local/bin/jabberlogs` with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# color for  highlighting usernames in chat:
COLOR=33

cd ~/.purple/logs;
for i in jabber/*/*/$1*; do 
  echo -e "\e[1;32m>>>>>> $i\e[0m";
  lynx -dump $i | sed 's/) \([[:alpha:][:digit:][:space:]@\.]*\):/) \x1b['${COLOR}'m\1\x1b[0m:/1'
done
```

Then you can easily search through your logs on the console with

```
jabberlogs 2014-06-09
```

---

Source for colorisazion: [colourize the first part of each line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136381/20661)

Comment: The logs are in HTML format so displaying them with **cat** won't be very helpful. `lynx -dump` might be a better option.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: On my Ubuntu the logs are not in html, but anyway, I added `lynx -dump` instead of just `cat` to my script

Comment: @rubo77, that's a bit strange. Pidgin migrated to HTML logs by default a long time ago. I even think it was called Gaim back then. For the record the setting is in **Tools** → **Preferences** → **Logging** → **Log format**.

Comment: Just beware of using **Control-l (lower-case L)**, which in many programs is the shortcut to insert a link: in **pidgin**, it deletes the conversation log! I have done this more than once...